# How to convert an HTML slides to Images in the server side?

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I have generated many HTML Slides in the PPT

sample slide in html

[image].

This HTML slides  needs to be captured and saved as an image in the server. While capturing the slides, it takes a lot of time in generating the images. And as the number of slides increases the capturing time also increases.

I am using the Canvas image capturing library.

This canvas renders the image in the client side and takes time. And if the client's PC has less configuration then it takes much longer time.

Is there a better way to capture the image in the server side so that the time taken to capture the image  becomes very less.